# Problema na impressão da string

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber qual o problema da minha string dentro da função, ela percorre a string e quando encontrar uma letra maiúscula transformar ela em minúscula (já tentei usar a `tolower` e `isupper`, mas não deu certo) e quando encontrar um ponto, exclamação, interrogação, dois pontos e ponto e virgula deve substitui-los por um espaço e a retorna para a main, mas ela não esta sendo alterada, segue abaixo o código da função:

```
char* diminuieretira(char** p, int r)//Declaração de função que converte as letras maiusculas em minusculas e adiciona no lugar das pontuações o espaço
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {

        if((*p[i]) >= 65 && (*p[i]) <= 90) //Se o caracter for maisculo
            (*p[i]) + 32; //Converto-o para minusculo

        else if((*p[i]) == 46 || (*p[i]) == 44 || (*p[i]) == 59 || (*p[i]) == 58 || (*p[i]) == 33 || (*p[i]) == 63); //Se o caracter for um ponto de exclamação, ponto, interrogação, dois pontos ou ponto e virgula
            (*p[i]) = 32; //Essa pontuação é substituida por um espaço
    }

    printf("%s", (*p)); //Imprimo na tela a strign modificada

    return (*p); //Retorno para a main a string modificada
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`(*p[i]) + 32;` não faz nada — esse comando soma 32 a `(*p[i])`, mas não faz nada com o resultado. Você quer

```
*p[i] = *p[i] + 32;
```

(os parênteses são desnecessários) ou, mais sucintamente

```
*p[i] += 32;
```

Comment: E para substituir os valores por espaço, seria errado fazer que *p[i] = 32???

Comment: Esse está certinho, mas eu usaria `*p[i] = ' '` pra deixar claro o que você está fazendo (idem pra `(*p[i]) == 46 || (*p[i]) == 44 || …`)

Comment: Continua dando algo errado, a mascara %s esta dendo usada corretamente por mim??

Comment: Se não quiser colocar explicito igual o @ctgPi falou, tu pode deixar a linha comentada explicando o que é cada valor. O costume de escrever comentários é muito útil pra você mesmo e para futuras pessoas que vão ver seu código, as vezes tu pode ficar um tempo sem ver o código e quando precisar não vai lembrar o que significa cada valor.

Comment: Se eu retiro o "*", o compilador acusa incompatibilidade de argumentos

Comment: Tentei usar o for mas da problema tambem

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa utilizar `char**` p nesta sua função, você pode utilizar apenas `char* p`, visto que você está trabalhando apenas em cima de uma string. Utilizar `char**` p vai deixar sua função mais confusa. E, a não ser que você queira modificar apenas parte da string, você também não precisa passar o tamanho da string (`int r`), você pode usar a função `strlen` no seu for.

O seu código `(*p[i]) + 32` não altera o valor de `*p[i]`, pois não há um sinal de igual. Ele não faz nada. E como você está usando um ponteiro duplo (`char**`), seria bom colocar escrever da seguinte forma: `(*p)[i]`, pois o * pode se referir ao `p` ou ao `p[i]`. É necessário alterar para: `(*p)[i] = (*p)[i] + 32`

E como @ctgPi falou, você pode colocar os símbolos diretamente para seu código ficar mais legível (ou colocar um comentário ao lado).
Então sua função ficaria assim:

```
char* diminuieretira(char* p)//Declaração de função que converte as letras maiusculas em minusculas e adiciona no lugar das pontuações o espaço
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(p); i++)
    {

        if(p[i] >= 65 && p[i] <= 90) //Se o caracter for maisculo
            p[i] += 32; //Converto-o para minusculo

        else if(p[i] == '.' || p[i] == ',' || p[i] == ';' || p[i] == ':' || p[i] == '!' || p[i] == '?'); //Se o caracter for um ponto de exclamação, ponto, interrogação, dois pontos ou ponto e virgula
            p[i] = ' '; //Essa pontuação é substituida por um espaço
    }

    printf("%s", p); //Imprimo na tela a strign modificada

    return p; //Retorno para a main a string modificada
}
```